# Odoo v10 how to make statusbar clickable on condition?

Tags: xml, odoo, statusbar, clickable

I want to make this field clickable only when user_id matches current user, tried it with readonly, attrs, options, nothing worked

```
<field name="stage_id" widget="statusbar" attrs="{'clickable':[('user_id','=','user.id')]}"/>
```

Comment: I don't see a chance doing that in xml records/view definition. Maybe you could set an id or class on the field and try to use that in a javascript extension of the statusbar widget?

Comment: Could You help me out with that?

Comment: No sorry, JS extensions for Odoo aren't my speciality xD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is for odoo 8, but it probably works for odoo 10.

You don't need to use quotes on `user.id`. Domains are evaluated with `safe_eval()`, which includes some variables such as `context` (current context dict), `user` (current user record), `time`(python's `time` module) and so on.

So you should try :

```
<field name="stage_id" widget="statusbar" attrs="{'clickable':[('user_id','=', user.id)]}"/>
```

If this still doesn't work, try to make the field readonly.

Answer (score 0):

Try out:

```
<field name="stage_id" widget="statusbar" attrs="{'clickable':[('user_id','=','uid')]}"/>
```

Comment: Doesn't work. It seems that problem is not in conditional,  cause if it was, if '=' doesn't work then '!=' would.